# Sou obrigado a definir o tamanho de uma LinkedList em Java?

Tags: java, lista

Uma vez que a `LinkedList` em Java é uma lista duplamente encadeada, entendo que eu poderia inserir um elemento em qualquer índice que eu quisesse, certo? Ou errado?

Por exemplo, eu crio uma lista e uso o método `add(indice, elemento)` para adicionar o primeiro elemento num índice com rótulo 5.

Ou não é assim, e eu só posso adicionar no início ou fim da lista e só posso colocar um elemento no índice 5 se tiver pelo menos 5 deles na lista?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta fazer um teste simples:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(1, "cde");
```

Esse código lança um `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, e o motivo está na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

O construtor sem argumentos [cria uma lista vazia](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList--) (ou seja, com tamanho zero):

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
System.out.println(list.size()); // 0
```

E o [método `add`, quando recebe um índice](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add-int-E-), lança a exceção `IndexOutOfBoundsException` se o valor do índice for menor quer zero ou maior que o tamanho da lista:

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

Como o tamanho da lista é zero, passar 1 para o método `add` lança a exceção.

---

Resumindo, só podemos usar índices que estejam entre zero e o tamanho da lista:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("def");
list.add(1,"xy");
System.out.println(list.size()); // 3
System.out.println(list); // [abc, xy, def]

list.add(3, "ultimo"); // índice é igual ao tamanho, é o mesmo que inserir no final
System.out.println(list); // [abc, xy, def, ultimo]

list.add(5,"abcde"); // IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: Isso que eu quis dizer. Ela não cria elementos em índices esparsos dinamicamente.

Answer (score 6):

Isto está bem confuso, usa termos que provavelmente só você sabe o que significa.

Uma lista ligada não deixa de ser uma lista, você pode inserir novos elementos dentro dela no começo, no fim e no meio, como em toda lista. A diferença dela para outras listas é o custo de fazer isto. Uma das vantagens da lista ligada é poder inserir no meio com complexidade O(1), ou seja, é constante, a mais baixa possível. Claro, ele tem esse custo se você estiver na posição que deseja, caso não esteja, e frequentemente não está tem um custo de deslocamento até lá, e esse custo que em muitas outras listas é O(1), na lista ligada o custo é O(n). O método que insere no meio da lista é o [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(int,E)). No que que a assinatura dele exige um índice, esse índice é para ser usado em um `get()` interno. O que acontece se você colocar um número de índice não existente em um `get()`, dá erro de faixa, certo?

Se a lista tem 5 elementos não pode inserir nada além do quinto elemento, ou seja não pode inserir no índice 6 (pode adicionar que é uma operação que não especifica onde vai inserir, é no final, ponto). Isto vale para qualquer lista, é física, você não pode colocar algo no índice 6 se só tem 5 elementos (vai do índice 0 ao 4, pode inserir no 5 porque é o mesmo que adicionar). Inserir é uma operação de chegar no elemento desejado e adicionar um elemento novo ali.

Note que criar um lista com um número de elementos (você pode ou não fazer isto) não garante que terá objetos nele, os objetos podem ser nulos, você teria que criar elementos e inicializá-los. Mas se desejar pode só adicionar elementos depois de criar a lista. O primeiro tem que ser no final já que não tem outros elementos. No início funciona também, não pode inserir no meio pela falta de elementos. Depois de existir pelo menos um elementos já pode inserir  no meio com o `add(index, value)`.

Comment: Rótulo de índice = quis dizer o índice em si: o endereço do elemento na lista.